# Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode

Tags: javascript

```
function serverReq(url,type,param)
{
    $.post(url, {
        "type":type,
        "jsonData":param,
        'userName':userName,
        "sessionId":sessionId
    }, function(responseText,status) {
        if(type === 'VALIDATE_USER'){
            if(responseText.trim() === 'true'){
                var jsonData = [];
                jsonData.push({'headerVal':'SFL_LOAN'});
                serverReq('webController.jsp?OD_UID='+odSessionId,'GET_DOC_GRP',jsonData);
            }
            else{
                $('.container').hide();
                alert('User have no rights to access Custom Search.');
            }
            
        }
        else if(type == 'GET_DOC_GRP'){
            renderDocGrp(responseText);
        }
        else if(type == 'GET_DOC_TYPE'){
            renderDocType(responseText);
        }
        else if(type == 'SRCH_DOC'){
            renderDocs(responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

In this code, serverReq is used to get response from the server and I'm getting an empty value as a response for responseText field. When I checked it with developer tools there was an exception "Getting TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode".

Comment: This part of your code doesn't use `.caller`, `.callee` or `.arguments`. Maybe `renderDocGrp` or `renderDocType` or `renderDocs` use those?

Comment: responseText value should be “True” before going inside if statement but I’m getting an responseText as empty value